# Compiling TV Card Drivers on Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: usb, raspbmc, driver

I own an August DVB-T208 Freeview TV Receiver. I would love to attach this tuner to a Raspberry Pi running OSMC. However, on the [drivers page on their website](http://www.augustint.com/en/downloadsoft-9.html), there are Linux drivers for this device available. I have downloaded these drivers and have discovered that they only support 32 and 64-bit devices. Since the Raspberry Pi runs an ARM processor, I assume that these will not be compatible. I was wondering if there was any way I could compile this driver for the Pi?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Nathan - did you get this working? I have the same receiver but haven't been able to work out how to build the driver..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ARM processors are mostly 32-bit, including the one in the pi.

However, the major issue will be that the driver must be built from source; distributing 32 and 64 bit versions implies these are pre-compiled for x86.

The .zip I checked does contain source and a makefile, so if you install the kernel source, you might be able to compile it on the pi.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind the august drivers, just follow these instructions:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=58757&p=440663

worked for me :)

Just had to answer this ...